# Check if Parent record exists using parent's External Id before inserting child

Tags: apex, upsert, externalid

I have a `child__c` object that has a lookup relationship to `Parent__c`. Each have an `ExternalId__c` field in them.

I am trying to create this relationship when inserting a child record.

```
    List<Child__c> childList = new List<Child__c>();
    for(wrapperObj wr : wrpList){
    Child__c c = new Child__c();
    string parentExtId = wr.Field1 + wr.Field2;
    Parent__c prnt = new Parent__c(External_ID__c = parentExtId);
    c.External_Id__c = wr.Field3 + wr.Field4;
    c.Parent__r = prnt;
    childList.add(c);
    }

upsert childList External_Id__c;
```

Using this approach I sometime get an error when a Parent doesn't exists with the same parent external Id combination `i.e. wr.Field1 + wr.Field2`. `Error - INVALID_FIELD, Foreign key external ID:XXX not found for field External_ID__c in entity Parent__c` .Is there a way to mitigate this error. As of now I do not want to do a SOQL on Parent.

Comment: How do you want to handle this error? You can throw it in a try catch statement and then take some action in the catch.

Comment: Are u saying there is no way to avoid error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option available is to use the `Database.upsert()` method with the `allOrNone` parameter set `false` and then look for errors in the results. This is helpful if partial success is acceptable.

```
Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(childList, External_Id__c, false);

for (Database.UpsertResult result : results) {

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // child upserted without error

    } else {
        // child could not be upserted
        Database.Error[] errorList = result.getErrors();

        // do something with the error list to inform the
        // caller of a partial failure
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i have to change my approach in that case. I was hoping not to use partial upsert.